# Angular regex validator not fully working

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I've created the below validator for a latitude input (Between -90 and 90 and excludes special characters (e, +, -, etc)). I've tested the regex and it works. However when I use this on an input it only validates the number range and allows special characters (e.g. '12e').

[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnY2X.png)

[Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHNec.png)
:

```
function validateLatCoordFactory(): ValidatorFn {
  return (formControl: AbstractControl) => {

    if(!formControl.value) return;

    let LAT_COORD_REGEXP = new RegExp(/^(\\+|-)?(?:90(?:(?:\.0{1,6})?)|(?:[0-9]|[1-8][0-9])(?:(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?))$/);

    return LAT_COORD_REGEXP.test(formControl.value) ? null : {
      validLatCoord: {
        valid: false
      }
    };
  };
}

@Directive({
  selector: '[validLatCoord][ngModel],[validLatCoord][formControl]',
  providers: [
    {provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: forwardRef(() => LatCoordValidatorDirective), multi: true}
  ]
})

export class LatCoordValidatorDirective implements Validator {

  validator: ValidatorFn;

  constructor() {
    this.validator = validateLatCoordFactory();
  }

  validate(formControl: AbstractControl) {
    return this.validator(formControl);
  }

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
BT7

Comment: can you create a plnkr/fiddle showcasing the problem? What does `formControl.value` contain? "12e" does not match the regex (http://jsfiddle.net/x5ty3kv6/1/) so it should return an error

Comment: As in my answer below, regex doesn't seem to be the right tool for this job. If you're going to stick with that avenue, however, this should be a more concise version of what you're using: `/^-?(?:[0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|90)(?:\.[0-9]{1,6})?$/`. If you're getting things like `12e` coming through, however, it seems more like the issue is with your error handling/filtering and not the regex itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that the value is between -90 and 90, inclusive, then you shouldn't be using regex in the first place.

```
let val = parseFloat(formControl.value)
return !!val && val == formControl.value && val >= -90 && val <= 90 ? null : { ...
```

This checks 3 things:

1. The value could be parsed as a float
2. The parsed value is the same as the initial value (the input wasn't 1.2341e23523, for example)
3. The value is between -90 and 90, inclusive